# DISTINCT count and sum in the same query

Tags: php, mysql

this is my table

```
id , tiket_id , agency , problem
 1  , 123     , 1      ,  x
 2  , 123     , 1      ,  y
 3  , 124     , 2      ,  z
```

i have a query that gives me the stats of the table based on the agency ,basically couple of counts and sums

```
 SELECT  COUNT(*) as total , 
 SUM(CASE WHEN `agancy` = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ag_1
 SUM(CASE WHEN `agancy` = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ag_2
```

but i want rows with the same ticket_id to be counted only once

for example the first two row have the same ticket id and they are actually one ticket .

i can do this for the total count

```
 SELECT  COUNT(distinct(ticket_id)) as total ,
```

i'm not  sure how to do this for the `SUM` ?
i know this doesn't works

```
 SUM(  DISTINCT ticket_id CASE WHEN `agancy` = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ag_1
```

Comment: Do you need to have only one result row? You can do it and have a row per agancy value.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you need only one result row:

```
select sum(cnt) as total, SUM(case when agency = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ag1, SUM(case when agency = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as ag2 from (     
    SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, agency
    from foo
    group by tiket_id,agency
) b
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cde84/1

Note that this assumes that two different agencies will not share a ticket_id.

Edit. Well, I reread your post, and I'm not sure if you want the TOTAL number of rows in the table or just the unique ticket ids. If you just want the unique ticket ids then you can do:

```
select COUNT(*) as total , SUM(case when agency = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as ag1, SUM(case when agency = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as ag2 from (        
    SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, agency
    from foo
    group by tiket_id,agency
) b;
```

See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cde84/5

Answer (score 0):

I would say use group by

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) as total , 
SUM(CASE WHEN `agancy` = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ag_1
SUM(CASE WHEN `agancy` = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ag_2
from mytable
group by tiket_id
```